# dealing with blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler

Tags: python, blobstore

I'm writing on GAE using python a server side for an iPad App. and one of the abilities is to save files on the server. I went through the blobstore examples and I can write similar test one that works. However, in my case, I have to divide the process in to two steps, one call to generate the URL and the other is to actually receive the file via blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler.
The issue is that the link I get from blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload') seems to be broken and my upload handler can't be found. The way I test this at the moment is via a static html file where I manually change the url to be the one I get from  blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
Any ideas why once I break the process into two the same code stops working?

Code:
Here is the function that returns the url which works well.

```
class GetUploadURL(webapp2.RequestHandler):
# this function will return the upload url to be used in a form
  def get(self):

        params=['session_id']

        has_params, missing_param = has_all_parameters(self,params)     

        if not has_params:
            show_error(self, MISING_PARAMS_ERROR, params)
            return      

        user = validate_session(self)
        if not user:
            show_error(self, UNKNOWN_SESSION_ID)
            return 

        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        ret_dict = { STATUS_CODE :STATUS_OK ,
                        UPLOAD_URL :  upload_url 
                       }`enter code here`
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(ret_dict))
```

and here is teh html i"m using locally and changing the upload_url with the long link I got form calling the function above

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="hidden" id="session_id" name="session_id" value="ahJkZXZ-ZGVzaWduZWRudG9maXRyDQsSB1Nlc3Npb24YDQw" >

    <a>Upload File: </a><input type="file" name="file">
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is where when I click submit it doesn't even get to the server, it's like a broken link.

Here is the function that should receive the post but it was never called

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
        params=['session_id']

        has_params, missing_param = has_all_parameters(self,params)     

        if not has_params:
            show_error(self, MISING_PARAMS_ERROR, params)
            return      

        user = validate_session(self)
        if not user:
            show_error(self, UNKNOWN_SESSION_ID)
            return 

        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        file1 = UserFile()
        file1.user = user
        file1.file_name= blob_info.filename
        file1.file_key = blob_info.key()
        file1.put()
        ret_dict = {STATUS_CODE: STATUS_OK,'file_key': str(file1.file_key)}
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(ret_dict))
```

Thanks for the help

Ran

Comment: What is the value returned from `create_upload_url`? And are you sure that you have configured a route pointing to `/upload`?